# How to test flash based applications using Selenium WebDriver or RC

Tags: flash, selenium, robotframework, sikuli

I have an application which contains videos and visual objects.

I need to test flash objects in that application using Selenium WebDriver or RC.
Give me the suggestions how to automate and what are the opensource tools to integrate with Selenium.

Except Sikuli and Robot, suggest me other approach(es) to automate the flash.

Thanks in advance friends......

Comment: Is it possible to modify the dev code by adding a third party files ??

Comment: I think by using swf file when compiling the code dev team should add swf file so that we can automate.dont know exactly..if its is wrong correct me friends..

Answer (score 0):

Flex Monkium can be used to automate the flash application using selenium. Using this flex monkium its possible to record the tests using selenium IDE and run the tests with some limitations (will run in IE only).

'https://www.gorillalogic.com/flexmonkium-docs/flexmonkium-setup'

All you need is to compile the application source code with the flex monkium created swc files which is version specific to flash and adding additional compiler arguments. 
Flex monkium connects the application and the selenium IDE, then the tests can be recorded using IDE itself.
**NOTE :** Flex Monkium is the free tool which has a minimal support from web.

Comment: is it useful to run test cases in FF,I want to know without compiling the source code with swc file we can automate or we cannot?

Comment: Ran I have seen this in html 

embed id="MediaWorkSpace" align="middle" width="100%" height="100%" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" allowscriptaccess="sameDomain" name="MediaWorkSpace" bgcolor="#ffffff" quality="high" src="MediaWorkSpace.swf"...

I want to know whether its is already compiled with swf file or not....Could you please suggest whether we can automate it using selenium

Comment: If you need to automate using flex monkium, you need to install flex monkium and generate your own 'flex-monkium-xyz.swc' file and copy it to the lib folder of the DEV source code. Then need to compile the dev code with additional compiler arguments related to the flex-monkium-xyz.swc file. Then you can automate the application using selenium.
'The same is clearly explained in the below url
https://www.gorillalogic.com/flexmonkium-docs/flexmonkium-setup'

Comment: If you want to automate without compiling the source code with third party swc files.. you can go for GENIE : http://sourceforge.net/adobe/genie/wiki/Home/ [UNTESTED]

Comment: Is it possible to integrate "Flex Monkium" with Selenium WebDriver?